# multiply model values on html

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I use asp.net-mvc, entity framework. My view is like below:

```
 <td class="center">
   <span id="spanitem_@item.UrunId">@item.Fiyat</span>
   <input type="text" id="textfiyat_@item.UrunId" value="" class="displaynone textwidth90"/>
 </td>
 <td class="center">
      <span id="spanitem_@item.UrunId">@item.Adet</span>
       <input type="text" id="textadet_@item.UrunId" value="" class="displaynone textwidth90"/>
</td>
<td class="center">
    <span id="spanitem_@item.UrunId">
      @item.Fiyat)*@item.Adet
    </span>
</td>
```

Fiyat field is decimal, Adet field is int. I want to show their multiplying. But i can not.
How can I achieve this. Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `@(item.Fiyat * item.Adet)`

Answer (score 0):

You can try it-

```
@(item.Fiyat * item.Adet)
```

Comment: You should have given an answer which is confirmed by you, please don't give an answer before testing.